# Is there a way to enable HTTPS connection in Picasso library on older devices?

Tags: java, android, https, picasso

My app is using images from HTTPS source, they're loading just fine on Android with API 21 or higher, but I can't load these images on Android versions from API 16 (min. API for my app) to API 19. Is there any way to enable TLS on older Android versions? It seems that it's enabled by default on Lollipop and higher. Help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to enable TLS on older Android versions?

TLS has been enabled in Android since Android 1.0. Specific levels of TLS, and specific root certificates, have varied over the years (and, in the case of certificates, might even vary by manufacturer on older devices).

> I can't load these images on Android versions from API 16 (min. API for my app) to API 19

Check LogCat for exceptions logged by Picasso. Or, run some tests where you directly download the image (e.g., OkHttp, `HttpURLConnection`), to ensure that you get the exceptions.

Then, if you do not understand how to address those exceptions, ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which would include your code, a URL that is failing, and the Java stack trace associated with the exception.

Comment: Also, maybe your certificate or the server is not compatible with those versions (obsolete or unsecure protocols disabled, for example). You can check with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable  http2 in pre-KitKat devices using OKHttp.

```
 List<Protocol> protocols = new ArrayList<>();
            protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_2);
            protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);



            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sc.init(null, null, null);

            ConnectionSpec cs = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                    .build();

            List<ConnectionSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
            specs.add(cs);
            specs.add(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
            specs.add(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT);

            mClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .protocols(protocols)
                    .connectionSpecs(specs)
                    .sslSocketFactory(new Tls12SocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()))
                    .build();
```

add this client to Picasso

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(mClient))
                        .build();
                Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
            }
```